# FlowLayout.encloseRightBottom not enclosing in bottom

Tags: codenameone

I have a custom container (a chat bubble) that contains a `SpanLabel`. The container obviously grows with the SpanLabel

Then I want to add a small label at the container's bottom right (a timestamp) using

`LayeredLayout.encloseIn(this, FlowLayout.encloseRightBottom(timeStampLabel));`.

I have followed the example shown in https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/layouts/LayeredLayout.html

This succeeds in laying the timestamp on the right, but not in the bottom. I suspect it may have something to do with the `SpanLabel` calculating its height? I will paste my code at the bottom. Thanks!

[image]

```
public class ChatBubble extends Container {

String _timestamp;
public ChatBubble(Boolean left, String text, String timestamp)
{
    _timestamp = timestamp;
    if(left)
        this.setUIID("ChatLeft");
    else
        this.setUIID("ChatRight");
    this.add(new SpanLabel(text+"         "));
}
public Container getBubble()
{
    Font smallSystemFont = Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL);
    Label timeStampLabel = new Label(_timestamp);
    timeStampLabel.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x888888);
    timeStampLabel.getAllStyles().setFont(smallSystemFont);

    return LayeredLayout.encloseIn(this,
            FlowLayout.encloseRightBottom(timeStampLabel));
}
}
```

...

```
ChatBubble bubble4 = new ChatBubble(false,"This is a very long stringThis is a very long stringThis is a very long stringThis is a very long stringThis is a very long string","11:42");
boxCenter.add(bubble4.getBubble());
```

Answer (score 1):

The flow layout works correctly but because of the span label it's hard for it to correctly calculate the height of the parent container in the early layout stage as that depends on the length of text + parent width. So you end up with the wrong position. A workaround would be to use a deterministic layout such as:

```
return LayeredLayout.encloseIn(this,
        BorderLayout.south(
             FlowLayout.encloseRightBottom(timeStampLabel)));
```

Another approach would be to use something like the rich text component instead of the `SpanLabel` + enclosing layout approach. E.g. https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-rich-view-revisited.html

Then you can just add the string to the end of the text with a different format.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first suggestion doesn't work. The second approach is fine but doesn't align the timestamp to the right which is my goal. Isn't there a way to append the timestamps after the height of the spanlabel has been calculated? Like overriding calcPreferredSize or similar

Comment: @JAnton I tried your code as it is, in a `Form` with a `BoxLayout.y()` layout: it works as you requested, putting the timestamp in the bottom right. You can see my screenshot here: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1997316/72661850-2f261c00-39d7-11ea-9c38-f2e84d3916f2.png

Comment: Not working for me sir. It also doesn't work when testing on Android. I tried your plain form approach too but no success. Then I added a `form.revalidate()` straight after `form.show()` and this took care of this. Weird

Comment: @JAnton You're right. I tried again your code in a bare bones project and a `revalidate()` after the `show()` is necessary. Previously I tested your code inside the app I'm developing and the `revalidate()` after the `show()` wasn't necessary: maybe some other code called a `revalidate()` for me, but I'm not aware why.

Comment: I think this might be another regression related to the `setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint` issue. As a workaround you can use `setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint(true)` but please file an issue with this test case.